# Can I parameterise the empty constraint type?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-constraints, type-families

I have a class for queues which allows the instance to define the constraints it places on the elements. For example, a priority queue requires its elements to be orderable:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, ConstraintKinds, FunctionalDependencies #-}

class Queue q c | q -> c where
    empty :: q a
    qpop :: c a => q a -> Maybe (a, q a)
    qpush :: c a => a -> q a -> q a

data PriorityQueue a = ...

instance Queue PriorityQueue Ord where
    ...
```

This works a charm: inside the instance declaration for `PriorityQueue` I can operate on elements of the queue using members of `Ord` such as `(>)`.

---

I've got stuck trying to define a queue which places no requirements on its elements:

```
newtype LIFO a = LIFO [a]

instance Queue LIFO () where
    empty = LIFO []
    qpop (LIFO []) = Nothing
    qpop (LIFO (x:xs)) = Just (x, LIFO xs)
    qpush x (LIFO xs) = LIFO $ x:xs
```

This fails, with the following error message from GHC:

```
The second argument of `Queue' should have kind `* -> Constraint',
  but `()' has kind `*'
In the instance declaration for `Queue LIFO ()'
```

This error message makes sense to me. `Eq` accepts a type parameter (we typically write `Eq a => ...`) whereas `()` has no parameters - it's a plain old kind mismatch.

---

I had a crack at writing a type function which ignores its second argument, which would allow me to write `instance Queue LIFO (Const ())`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, KindSignatures, PolyKinds #-}

type family Const a b :: k -> k2 -> k
type instance Const a b = a
```

I find this interaction of type families and kind polymorphism quite beautiful, so I was rather disappointed when it didn't work (I really thought it would!):

```
Expecting two more arguments to `a'
The first argument of `Const' should have kind `*',
  but `a' has kind `k0 -> k1 -> k0'
In the type `a'
In the type instance declaration for `Const'
```

I have a feeling this last example is something stupid like a syntax mistake (I'm new to type families). How can I write a `Constraint` which doesn't place any restrictions on its argument?

Comment: Try defining `type family Const (a :: k1) (b :: k2) :: k1` then `Const (() :: Constraint)` has the kind you want, however it still gets stuck.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson Yeah, it seems to get stuck at the `instance` declaration: `Illegal type synonym family application in instance`. Why did my original attempt at `Const` fail?

Comment: You may be also interested in doing this just with `TypeFamilies`. http://www.skybluetrades.net/blog/posts/2015/03/08/constraint-kinds-associated-types.html

Comment: @snak Thanks for the link. That looks like a pretty straightforward translation of my `FunctionalDepenencies` version into `TypeFamilies`. (This is quite reasonable, since type families generalise functional dependencies.) Personally I prefer functional dependencies here but it's purely a taste issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
class NoConstraint a where
instance NoConstraint a where

instance Queue LIFO NoConstraint where
  ...
```

The above defines a constraint which is satisfied by all types. As such, the obligations `c a` where `c = NoConstraint` can always be discharged.
Also, since there are no members in that class, it should have zero (or nearly zero) run-time cost.

The "constraint" `()` you are trying to use is not seen as an empty constraint set by GHC, but as the unit type `() :: *`. This causes `Const () :: k2 -> *`, which triggers the kind error.

If you do not want to use a custom class, you might try e.g. `Const (Eq ())` or `Const (Num Int)`, which have the right kind `k2 -> Constraint`. I do not recommend this, though, since I find it less readable than using a custom class.

(This requires to enable some extensions, as Benjamin Hodgson points out below in a comment.)

Comment: Thanks! In fact, I independently arrived at that solution moments before your answer! I think it's worth pointing out that this requires `FlexibleInstances`, and works best with `PolyKinds` and `KindSignatures` turned on as well (so you can write `class NoConstraint (a :: k)` - otherwise GHC will assume `a :: *`).

Comment: The problem I see here is that the `NoConstraint` constraint will "infect" everything using the queue. Would it be possible to get around this using `Const (NoConstraint ())`?

Comment: @dfeuer If you're using the queue generically, the constraint looks like `(Queue q c, c a) => q a` which I think is not too onerous

Comment: @dfeuer If you use `Queue` generically, then only `c a` is generated, and `NoConstraint a` is not involved. If instead you use the specific `Queue LIFO` instance, then `Constraint a` will be generated and then immediately discharged. So this should never "infect" any signatures in the code, as far as I can see.